# Update before screenshot

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gdi+, screenshot

I want to capture an image of the screen, however there are some wpf controls in my application that I do not want to appear in the screenshot. Using the code below, the hidden controls will sometimes still appear in the screenshot. How do I ensure that this doesn't happen?

```
Window window = new Window();
Button button = new Button();

void ShowWindow()
{
    button.Content = "button";
    button.ToolTip = "tooltip";
    window.Content = button;
    window.Show();

    button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
}

void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Hide some controls and all tooltips in the window
    ToolTipService.SetIsEnabled(window, false);
    button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    //Block until wpf renders
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, 
        new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate { }));

    //Take screenshot
    Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                0, 0,
                                System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);

    //Restore controls and tooltips
    button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ToolTipService.SetIsEnabled(window, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a low priority on the dispatcher, it still isn't a guarantee though ([source](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=380674)).

Also, from my understanding WPF doesn't start the render process until the UI thread is idle (or lengthily blocked), so you may want to place the dispatch blocking & snapshot code in an actual background thread (or have the dispatcher asynchronously invoke the snapshot code). Then restore the button visibility once that snapshot thread is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks like it is impossible to tell whether a change to a wpf control has been rendered.

Comment: This answer was the most helpful. What I want to do is impossible (to do deterministically). The best bet is to try some tricks that will hopefully cause the render thread to run and finish rendering before the capture, though so far is I can tell there is no way to guarantee this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `DispatcherPriority` to `Normal` rather than `Background`?

Comment: Or Render, instead of Normal/Background

Comment: Changing DispacherPriority does not appear to help. I believe that this line works by forcing all actions of higher priority to be processed. So in order to force a render, it needs to have a lower priority than render.  However, even changing it to lowest priority does not fix the problem.

Comment: Interesting, and a fair point.  IIRC, the actual rendering in WPF is done in another thread (not the dispatcher thread), so just because the dispatcher is finished doesn't mean the pixels are on the screen yet.  I'm not sure if that information is available upstream where you are... sorry :)